# Identify values of 1 and replace them by 0 in a data.frame R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame in R

```
   L1 L2        L3        L4       L5 L6 L7
1  0  0 0.0000000 0.7142857 0.2857143  0  0
2  0  0 0.1052632 0.8947368 0.0000000  0  0
3  0  0 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000  0  0
4  0  0 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000  0  0
5  0  0 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000  0  0
6  0  0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000  0  0
7  0  0 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000  0  0
```

I need to change the values of `1.0000000` by 0.

Comment: Doesn`t work, the values in DF[3,3] still 1 as well as the value DF[5,5].

Comment: Great work, could you tell me (broadly) what was wrong?

Comment: working so fine for me, cheers